# Effective number of independent tests, M(eff), to FDR adjusted p-values

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I am trying to adjust a set of raw p-values with FDR method (BH). 
One of the assumptions in BH method is test independence. I know that some tests are clones and another ones are testing a very similar event.

Consequently, FDR correction is biased. I applied the simpleM method (described by Gao et. al [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19434714))
and estimated my effective number of independent tests, M(eff), to be equal to 1096, while my total number of tests was 3243.

The simpleM gave me the M(eff), however, I don´t know which tests have to be considered and carried to FDR correction and subsequent analysis.

Any ideas to subset all my tests in a representative group?

Comment: I had the same question and found it in J. Li & L. Ji, Heredity (2005) 95, 221–227. (doi:10.1038/sj.hdy.6800717)